# Typescript infer props doesn't work for Intrinsic elements

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component which takes an `as` prop and should infer the remaining prop types from that:

```
import React from 'react';
import s from './index.module.scss';

export type LayoutProps<As extends React.ComponentType<any> | keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements> = {
  as: As;
} & React.ComponentProps<As>;

export function Layout<As extends React.ComponentType<any> | keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements>({
  as: Component = 'div',
  children,
  className = '',
  ...props
}: LayoutProps<As>) {
  return (
    <Component className={`${s.layout} ${className}`} {...props}>
      {children}
    </Component>
  );
}
```

This works fine for standard React components, for example the following would throw the error `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
const Example = () => <Layout as={Link} title={5}>Hello</Layout>;
```

This however works when it should in fact throw the same error:

```
import React from 'react';
const Example = () => <Layout as="a" title={5}>Hello</Layout>;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you planning to do something  like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-meadow-4218t?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: Yes, however that example seems to have the same issue as my code...